# How to inform the user that the number shown in a list is incomplete or might not be current?

Tags: icons, lists, color-perception

**Consider this card shown below:**

[image]

It's a card with a list view showing the total income by teams. Now most of these teams have secondary teams under them. And many times the actual number of one of the teams could missing, pending or known to be incorrect. For a user who is looking at this card for information, how can I indicate that some numbers are incorrect or incomplete?

Some solutions and their drawbacks:

**Warning Icons next to the number** 
[image]

Issues:

- The icons is used in the app to indicate major warnings everywhere.
  Some might consider this a big deal. Whereas, the incompleteness is
  just temporary

**Flag icon**

[image]

Issues:

- List item

Its not actually a flagged item.

**Coloring the number**

[image]

Issues:
Users might consider these numbers to hold more weight than the others. This could skew a few decisions.

Welcome all suggestions and questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possibilities. An option is the one DropBox uses for the ready and updating files:

- The updated files have a green check icon
- The files to be updated have a blue icon with the rotating arrows animation

[image]

Comment: I like this idea

Answer (score 1):

> And many times the actual number of one of the teams could missing, pending or known to be incorrect. For a user who is looking at this card for information, how can I indicate that some numbers are incorrect or incomplete?

1. It is important to have an appropriate indicator to represent all three conditions: Possibly missing/ pending/ incorrect.
2. My argument with the sync icon as suggested above is that it does not cover the potential data inaccuracy. It's more like 'The data is available but is not yet sync/ updated here'.

Creative Cloud uses a warning icon and the icon is clickable to explain the error. It also provides a 'Learn More' link which further explains the potential cause of the error.

[image]
[image]

This reference might be more complex than you'd expect for your card list but I believe there are things that you could adapt. You can explain the potential cause of error perhaps in a tooltip instead of larger container. It will have the user better informed on the error and root cause. It will also nudge the user to work on the solution to remove the error and indirectly encourage data completion/accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer tags as they're more readable and are easily understandable; no need to put extra elements to explain the user what they mean. They can also be easily sorted, where it doesn't make sense to sort simple icons (in my opinion).
[image]